# Por que me da error la camara en expo?

Tags: android, expo

me esta saliendo el siguiente error, al intentar utilizar la camara desde expo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: Este es mi codigo]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En vez de imágenes, pon el código, te lo agradecerá la comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

tu codigo se ve bien, el unico error es

```
if (cameraRef) { ...
```

esto siempre sera verdadero.

```
if ({ current: null }) // always true
```

entonces, claramente debe de ser

```
if (cameraRef.current)
```